# How to overlay text over images that have been mapped on a horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I created a horizontal scrollbar that shows the image posters for a group of movies (e.g. "Popular Today", "Top of All Time"). Currently, when you hover over an image it creates a basic transition zoom animation, but my goal is to make it so when you hover, it creates overlay text over the image and changes the background to show more information about the movie like title, release date, genre, etc. I tried implementing an overlay; however, the position situation poses a problem. Setting overlay to absolute doesn't allow text to match each poster while scrolling and setting it to relative (which I currently have it set to) creates margin problems.

Here is my return div

```
return(
    <div>
        <h3 className='sliderTitle'>{props.title}</h3>  
        <div className='sliderStyle'>
            {movs.map((mov) => {
                    return (
                    <div>
                        <img key={mov.original_title} className='posterStyle' src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280${mov.poster_path}`} alt="/"/>
                        <div className='imageOverlay'>
                            <p className='imageDescription'> Information goes Here! </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    )
            })
        </div>             
    </div>
    )
```

and here is my CSS

```
.sliderStyle {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;

}

.posterStyle{
    width: 250px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.posterStyle:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: all .5s;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}


.sliderTitle {
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: #DC143C;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.imageOverlay{
    position: relative;
    background: orange;
    color: white;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any insight. Here is an image of what it currently looks like for [aid](https://imgur.com/a/4HjTDUc)

Like I stated before, I have tried changing the position to absolute (like most tutorials suggest) but absolute does not keep the text aligned while scrolling and changing properties like 'top' loses the text. If you set it to relative it creates a margin at the bottom and changing properties like 'top' and 'bottom' works to put the text in the center of the image but it creates a large gap at the bottom of the scrollbar.